# How to see c++ link command in VS 2012

Tags: c++, hyperlink

I can see the full cl commands via setting the Supress Startup Banner to "No" in IDE. But just got below information for Link

```
>Link:
1>     Creating library C:\Users\shu6889.CHN\work\gitlab\runtime\raster\codes\study\GDALStudy\Debug\HelloWorld.lib and object C:\Users\shu6889.CHN\work\gitlab\runtime\raster\codes\study\GDALStudy\Debug\HelloWorld.exp
1>  GDALStudy.vcxproj -> C:\Users\shu6889.CHN\work\gitlab\runtime\raster\codes\study\GDALStudy\Debug\HelloWorld.exe
```

How to show the full link command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your project, go to the property, click on Linker, the options appear to the right. The second option should be:

```
Show Progress     Not Set
```

Change that option to /VERBOSE to get pretty much everything. Feel free to test the other options to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I find the correct setting in Linker settings, just change Suppress Startup Banner to "No", then I can see the Link arguments.

"/OUT:C:\...\HelloWorld.exe" /INCREMENTAL /LIBPATH:C:\...\libs\x86 gdal_id.lib ... comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST "/MANIFESTUAC:level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG "/PDB:C:\...\HelloWorld.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT "/IMPLIB:C:\...\Debug\HelloWorld.lib" /MACHINE:X86 HelloWorld.obj 
1>  Debug\stdafx.obj

Comment: Ah! Yes! There is that one too. The one I proposed would also tell you from which directory each library is taken. That can be useful if you were to have multiple copies of the library you are linking against.